# Catch Webhook entries and place on new .csv line

Tags: php

I am trying to add webhook data into a .CSV file that is created (if it doesn't) exist and adds the data to a new line in the same .CSV file (if it does exist). The problem that I am experiencing is that when the webhook catches data the first time I can get the new file .CSV created and have the data added. If the webhook catches a different set of data a new line with that information is NOT being created or even added to the .CSV file. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a payload sample:

```
    Array
(
    [lead_id] => lead_id1
    [form_id] => form_id1
    [user_column_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column_name] => Full Name
                    [string_value] => John Doe
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [column_name] => User Phone
                    [string_value] => 12345678
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [column_name] => User Email
                    [string_value] => abc@123.com
                )

        )

    [api_version] => 1.0
    [google_key] => secret
)
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$events = json_decode($data, true);

$users  = $events['user_column_data'];

 $columns = false;

 $filename = "user_responses.csv";

 if( ! file_exists( $filename ) ){
     $columns = array( 
         "User Name", 
         "User Phone", 
         "User Email Address"
     );
 }

foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    if( $columns ){
        $columns[] = strip_tags( $value['column_name'] ) . " ({$value['string_value']})";
    }

}     

$fp = fopen( $filename, "a+" );
if( $columns ){
    fputcsv( $fp, $columns );
}
fclose( $fp );

http_response_code(200);
```

?>

On top of everything, I cannot even get the data to fall under the heading that I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only initializing the `$columns` array if the file doesn't exist. If the file exists, your `$columns` is not defined, and `foreach ($users...` loop doesn't add any entries there. You should get rid of the `if ($columns)` check.

Furthermore, your `foreach ($users...` loop iterates over whole rows, not over fields. Each `$value` in your loop is a row, an array of columns.